# Trying to do a "join" on a ListField(ReferenceField(...))

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb, mongoengine, flask-restful

I have documents like this

**class Users(Document):**

```
name = StringField(required=True)
email = EmailField(required=True, primary_key=True)
preferences = ListField(ReferenceField(Preferences, required=True))
languages = ListField(ReferenceField(Languages), required=True)
```

**class Languages(Document):**

```
name = StringField(required=True,unique=True)
active = BooleanField(default=True)
```

**class Preferences(Document):**

```
name = DictField(required=True,unique=True)
active = BooleanField(default=True)
```

I am trying to retrieve information from these 3 collections .
return code from my python

```
output = Users.objects.aggregate([
                {
                    '$lookup':
                        {
                            "from": "languages",
                            "localField": "languages",
                            "foreignField": "_id",
                            "as": "languages"
                        }
                },
                {
                    '$lookup':
                        {
                            "from": "preferences",
                            "localField": "preferences",
                            "foreignField": "_id",
                            "as": "preferences"
                        }
                }
            ])
            return jsonify({'result': output})
```

but getting below error :

File "D:\user.py", line 51, in get
return jsonify({'result': output})
File "C:\Users\Ideapad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Lib\site-packages\flask\json_*init*_.py", line 355, in jsonify
f"{dumps(data, indent=indent, separators=separators)}\n",
File "C:\Users\Ideapad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Lib\site-packages\flask\json_*init*_.py", line 133, in dumps
rv = *json.dumps(obj, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Ideapad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Lib\json_*init**.py", line 238, in dumps
**kw).encode(obj)
File "C:\Users\Ideapad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Lib\json\encoder.py", line 201, in encode
chunks = list(chunks)
File "C:\Users\Ideapad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Lib\json\encoder.py", line 431, in _iterencode
yield from _iterencode_dict(o, _current_indent_level)
File "C:\Users\Ideapad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Lib\json\encoder.py", line 405, in _iterencode_dict
yield from chunks
File "C:\Users\Ideapad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Lib\json\encoder.py", line 438, in _iterencode
o = *default(o)
File "C:\Users\Ideapad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Lib\site-packages\flask_mongoengine\json.py", line 19, in default
return superclass.default(self, obj)
File "C:\Users\Ideapad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Lib\site-packages\flask\json_*init**.py", line 57, in default
return super().default(o)
File "C:\Users\Ideapad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Lib\json\encoder.py", line 179, in default
raise TypeError(f'Object of type {o.**class**.**name**} '
TypeError: Object of type CommandCursor is not JSON serializable

Answer (score 0):

its working fine with the json.dumps

dumps(output, ensure_ascii=False)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).